# Integration of motion using resistance and gravity.

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble with a high school mathematics question.
An object of mass $1kg$ falls from rest in a medium in which the resistance to motion is given by $r=kv^2$, where $k$ is a constant and $v$ is the speed.

Prove that the distance, $x$, fallen when the velocity is $v$ is given by:
$$x=\frac{1}{2k}log_e\left(\frac{g}{g-kv^2}\right )$$

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a high school calculation (I need to figure it out)
The governing equation
$$
\text{Resultant Force} = \text{Force due to gravity} -\text{resistive Force}
$$
thus using newtons law of 
$$
\text{Force} = \text{mass}\times\text{acceleration} = ma
$$
We derive the following
$$
ma = m\frac{dv}{dt} = mg - kv^2
$$
knowing that $v = \dfrac{dx}{dt}$, where $x$ is the distance traveled, we find
$$
m\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = mg - k\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2
$$
Where 
$$
a = \dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
for mass $m = 1kg$ we find
$$
\ddot{x} = g - k\dot{x}^2
$$ 
can we solve this (or even use this method for HS I do not know)
$$
\ddot{x} = \dfrac{dx}{dt}\dfrac{d}{dx}\dot{x} = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\dot{x}^2 = g - k\dot{x}^2
$$re-arrange to find
$$
\frac{1}{g-k\dot{x}^2}d(\dot{x}^2) = 2dx \implies -\frac{1}{k}\ln \left(g-k\dot{x}^2\right) = 2x + C
$$
remember $\dot{x} = v$ we have
$$
-\frac{1}{k}\ln \left(g-kv^2\right) = 2x + C
$$
lets find $C$ we have $x(t=0) = v(t=0) = 0$ (my assuming that we start with x(0) = 0)
$$
-\frac{1}{k}\ln g = C
$$
so we have 
$$
2x = -\frac{1}{k}\ln \left(g-kv^2\right) +-\frac{1}{k}\ln g  = -\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\frac{g-kv^2}{g}\right) = \frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\frac{g}{g-kv^2}\right)
$$
so
$$
x = \frac{1}{2k}\ln\left(\frac{g}{g-kv^2}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know completely understand! This is just a question I have been given by my maths teacher. Definitely our high school grade maths.

Comment: When it comes to solving $x¨=g-kv^2$ I'm completely lost

Comment: This is why I think my solution does not satisfy your requirements. Have you worked with differential equations?

Comment: Yes, towards rectilinear motion
We have done these also:
1. Integration by parts
2. Variable forces
3. Newton's laws and antiderivatives of such etc
4. Substitution where the derivative is present in the integrand
5. Linear substitution
6. Trigonometric integration
7. Definite integrals

Pretty much all the stuff assumed by my teacher to be able to cover this question.

Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure how just knowledge of integration by parts will help you here. I will keep thinking. Do you have any idea how the problem should be solved? initial equations? - failing that I will give a short edit on solving the equation you start in the comment above.

Comment: Sorry i was messing up my edits consistently

Comment: NP. Are you happy with the chain rule $\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dt}\times \dfrac{dv}{dx}$

Comment: Yes i understand the chain rule 110%

Comment: I've picked up on some implicit differentiation in some of the derivation above also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31190/discussion-between-chinny84-and-brayden).

Comment: I understand it all now and solved the rest of the questions! Thanks